# **[Assert] Error in UIKit client: -[UIWindow setScreen:] should not be called if the client adopts UIScene lifecycle

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Getting this error while we try to present alert from library. need help to setup UIWindow on SceneDelegate.

```
[Assert] Error in UIKit client: -[UIWindow setScreen:] should not be called if the client adopts UIScene lifecycle. Call -[UIWindow setWindowScene:] instead.
```

I've been seeing the error as well on anything developed with UIKit that presents new views.  I'm not sure it's not an unfinished underlying api issue with the new separation of functionality into SceneDelegate from AppDelegate, as nowhere in any of my project code do I directly call setScreen.

My current code is below

```
       let contentView = ContentView()
       let vc1 = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
       let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = nav
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The system ui element RPSystemBroadcastPickerView does not function in an application using new UIScene lifecycle.

When tapping the Start Broadcast button, the broadcast does not start and the following error is seen in the logs:
[Assert] Error in UIKit client: -[UIWindow setScreen:] should not be called if the client adopts UIScene lifecycle. Call -[UIWindow setWindowScene:] instead.

This view works as expected when using the AppDelegate to manage the application lifecycle.